# decoder JPEG not available (using virtualenv)

Tags: python, jpeg, python-imaging-library, decoder

I'm getting this error, when system tries to download jpeg file. I think I tried all possible solutions (that I found on internet), I installed/uninstalled `PIL`, then tried `Pillow` using `pip`. Then added symbolink links like this:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so /usr/lib/libjpeg.so
```

It just says file exists. When I uninstall Pillow and try to install again (in virtualenv), I get these warnings:

```
warning: no files found matching '*.yaml'
warning: no files found matching '*.bdf' under directory 'Images'
warning: no files found matching '*.fli' under directory 'Images'
warning: no files found matching '*.gif' under directory 'Images'
warning: no files found matching '*.icns' under directory 'Images'
warning: no files found matching '*.ico' under directory 'Images'
warning: no files found matching '*.jpg' under directory 'Images'
warning: no files found matching '*.pbm' under directory 'Images'
warning: no files found matching '*.pil' under directory 'Images'
warning: no files found matching '*.png' under directory 'Images'
warning: no files found matching '*.ppm' under directory 'Images'
warning: no files found matching '*.psd' under directory 'Images'
warning: no files found matching '*.tar' under directory 'Images'
warning: no files found matching '*.webp' under directory 'Images'
warning: no files found matching '*.xpm' under directory 'Images'
warning: no files found matching 'README' under directory 'Sane'
warning: no files found matching 'README' under directory 'Scripts'
warning: no files found matching '*.icm' under directory 'Tests'
warning: no files found matching '*.txt' under directory 'Tk'
```

How can I fix this?

**P.S. I'm using Debian squeez and python2.7 on virtualenv.**